# how to get slide indicator to match current slide?

Tags: javascript

I have made this vanilla js image slider with three images. In the html i have three indicator dots at the bottom of the slider and a css active class for the active indicator.  Can't figure out how to get the class to add to the current slide of the slide show, any help?

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slides'),
    prevArrow = document.querySelector('#prevBtn'),
    nextArrow = document.querySelector('#nextBtn'),
    dots = document.querySelectorAll('.indicator__dot'),
    current = 0;


reset = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i <sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

}

startSlide = () => {
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block'
}

prevSlide = () => {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = 'block';
    current -- ;
}

nextSlide = () => {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
    current++;
}


prevArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(current === 0 ) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    prevSlide();
});

nextArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(current === sliderImages.length - 1 ) {
        current = -1
    }
    nextSlide();

});


startSlide()
```

Comment: Do you want to add 'active' class to the slides? If so, why not simply add `sliderImages[0].classList.add("active")` to  `startSlide` (and `prevSlide`, `nextSlide` with respective index) and `sliderImages[i].classList.remove("active")` on `reset` function?

Answer (score 0):

No sorry I should have been more clear and included some html.  I have 3 dots at the bottom of the slider.  When slide one is the current image the first dot will have the css class added to it, when the second image is showing the second do will have the active class and the first dot wont any more. Hope that makes more sense?

```
<div class="indicator">
     <span class="indicator__dot">&nbsp</span>
     <span class="indicator__dot">&nbsp</span>
     <span class="indicator__dot">&nbsp</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this so may have some bugs. `setAnchor()` function resets all the dots and add `active` class to the `current` dot.

```
setAnchor = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i <dots.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].classList.remove("active");

    if(current === i){
      sliderImages[i].classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}

startSlide = () => {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current].style.display = 'block'
    setAnchor();
}

prevSlide = () => {
    reset();
    current -- ;
    sliderImages[current].style.display = 'block';
    setAnchor();
}

nextSlide = () => {
    reset();
    current++;
    sliderImages[current].style.display = 'block';
    setAnchor();
}
```